# date range search result wrong because of time stamp in UTC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, datetime

HI I have problem with my date time search logic in our database we store datetime in utc and view it in front in to localtime and that create some problem and confuse users who search for record.I am using angular asp.net web Api and EF.

first angularjs layer user select date and enter From date and to date and send it to web api

```
   var searchForms = function(searchOption, searchText) {
        var url = 'api/' + searchText + '/searchid';
        if (searchOption === 'date') {

            var fromDateEpoch = moment.utc(searchText.fromDateSearch);
            var toDateEpoch = moment.utc(searchText.toDateSearch);
            var fromDate = moment(fromDateEpoch).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
            var toDate = moment(toDateEpoch).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');

             url = ' api/' + fromDate + '/' + toDate + '/searchDateRange' ;
        }

        return $http.get(url)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    };
```

the web api get thr request and EF qaury data
Web api

```
 public IEnumerable<FormViewModelBase> GetFormsByDateRange(string fromDate, string toDate)
    {

        var fromDateSearch = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var toDateSearch = DateTime.ParseExact(toDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var result = new List<serchResultModel>();
        using (var db = new AthenaContext())
        {
            var patientForms = (from Patient in db.PatientForms
                                       where
                                           (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(Patient.Date) >= fromDateSearch.Date &&
                                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(Patient.Date) <= toDateSearch.Date)
                                       select Patient).ToList();

              result.AddRange(patientForms);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

for example the data if We have records dated  2015-07-15 01:26:35 in UTC time and our time is local New-York time(note: we convert to local time in front end).the user search from 2015-07-15 to 2015-07-29.the result will include all records form 2015-07-14 to 2015-07-29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found out what is the issue it is because of database don't store off Timezone Off set for the user beouse of that we need to convert stored data from UTC time zone  to local-time zone using SQL update

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your local offset from Angular app to the API and then use it to offset the searched date range.

To get your client timezone offset you can use something like:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

This will return you client timezone offset as a difference between client's local time and UTC in minutes (e.g. -600 for UTC +10).

Answer (score 0):

If you are both storing in UTC and treating the user's input as UTC it shouldn't be returning 2015-07-14.  I wonder if your problem may be the second invocation of moment, which may be taking the first moment.utc and mistakenly treating it as local time.  Does this work better?

```
 var fromDateEpoch = moment.utc(searchText.fromDateSearch);
 var toDateEpoch = moment.utc(searchText.toDateSearch);
 var fromDate = fromDateEpoch.format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
 var toDate = toDateEpoch.format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
```